# Delete and Redeploy Rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have a rails app that is deployed to Heroku. I recently made a ton of changes, deleted old migrations, recreated new migrations, rebased and dealt with merge conflicts....the list goes on.

Now, I want to wipe my entire heroku "production" app from heroku and redeploy my code from my github `master` branch to Heroku.

Is there an easy or "right" way to delete my app on Heroku, wipe it clean, and then redeploy?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you don't want to delete the entire application (perhaps you want to keep your add-ons and other configuration the same), you can reset the database and force update the code.

Deploy your new code, forcing the update by using the `-f` flag:

```
git push heroku master -f
```

Drop and recreate the database:

```
heroku pg:reset <DATABASE>
```

Migrate the fresh database:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I was so in need of that -f thank  you carlosramireziii

Comment: what about temp files

Answer (score 119):

Destroy the app:

```
heroku apps:destroy --app example
```

Create a new one:

```
heroku create example
```

Push to it:

```
git push heroku -u master
```

[image: Screen grab from Heroku Tool belt]