# Redeploy Heroku app without code changes

Tags: heroku

I would like to deploy a Heroku app which will be done ideally using `git push -u heroku master`. However this will only work if there are any pending commits to be pushed to master.

How can I redeploy the app while there is nothing to push ? I tried `git push -u heroku master -f` and still get the same below

```
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from heroku.
Everything up-to-date
```

PS: I also want to retain the existing app, which means I cannot make use of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22043184/968442

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you hope to achieve by redeploying the same code again?

Comment: A case where I changed the few configvars, which deserves a redeployment but no commits

Comment: [Setting a config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application) causes your application to be restarted. It should take effect without needing to redeploy. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Unfortunately the configvar that I removed was `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`, Which is supposed to invoke another Django command `manage.py collectstatic` which is hooked into heroku deployment logic.

Comment: In my case, I updated a git submodule which doesn't trigger a restart

Answer (score 247, accepted):

Normally setting a config var causes your application to be restarted. In most situations there should be no need to redeploy after doing this.

If you really do need to trigger a new deployment you can add a new empty commit, then push to Heroku again:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger Heroku deploy after enabling collectstatic"
git push heroku master
```

The new empty commit is a regular commit. It has a hash, an author, a timestamp, etc. It will have the same tree as its parent. This should cause Heroku to build your app slug again using the same code as the previous commit.

It's a bit awkward, but it works.

Comment: Sounds fair enough and does the job. Now I get tempted to backup/restore the repository(`.git`) to hide this commit from github.

Comment: @itsneo, I wouldn't bother. It's an ugly commit, but if you keep writing code on top of the previous commit you'll have to force push to Heroku the next time. That's not a great habit to get into, although it can be necessary sometimes…

Comment: Even with `git commit --allow-empty` I am receiving `Everything up-to-date` from Heroku...

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer, please look at your `git log`. Did you successfully create a new commit before pushing?

Comment: Ah, I see the issue! I was in a different local branch (than `master`). So I had to execute: `git push -f heroku the_branch_i_changed:master`.

Comment: just do `git commit --amend; git push heroku master -f` without actual changes, unless you have strict rules about rewriting public branch history.

Comment: My JS assets are built during the deploy process, and they rely on ENV vars. So even if my app is restarted when I set an ENV var, my JS won't get rebuilt unless I do a deploy. ...just pointing this out cuz there are legit scenarios where one would want to redeploy

Answer (score 77):

You can do it from UI as well!

1. Login to your `Heroku` dashboard and go to `deploy` section
2. Find `Manual deploy` option

Hit `Deploy Branch` button!

[image]

Note: you must have your app connected to GitHub for this option to be available (see comment from Derek below).

Comment: It's worth noting that you must have your app connected to GitHub for this option to be available. If you're using the Heroku Git deployment method without having connected the app to its GitHub repo, it's not immediately obvious how to deploy manually.

Comment: Agreed, but it is reasonable, heroku dashboard, click the deploy tab, click the connect to github button, type in your github repo in the search field, confirm and you are connected. I believe when connected it auto deploys on push.

Comment: Using Heroku Git deployment you need to rename `master` branch to `main` branch to allow deploy manually

Answer (score 15):

There is now also a plugin for the Heroku command-line that allows you to re-release the most recently deployed slug.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/heroku-releases-retry

Comment: At first I thought this is the solution, but actually it does only redploy but not rebuild. But there is a way to also rebuild without tainting you Git history by pushing a new commit: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9713183/322863

Comment: What is Python projects to do with npm ?

Comment: @nehem The npm package is a script to deploy a code package on Heroku. It has nothing to do with the type of project, whether Python or anything else. Its effectively the equivalent of a shell script

Answer (score 14):

> It turns out there is a neat plugin for Heroku called heroku release retry that lets you retry the last deploy without resorting to adding bad commits to your repository.

```
// install plugin
heroku plugins:install heroku-releases-retry
// retry release
heroku releases:retry --app {your-app}
```

Source: https://www.darraghoriordan.com/2019/03/02/heroku-push-failed-force-rebuild

Answer (score 4):

You can run `heroku restart --app app_name` and you are good to go.

Comment: This doesn't rebuild the app, it only restarts it

Comment: @PanMan The question says "How can I redeploy the app while there is nothing to push ?". It's not asking for the app to rebuild but to restart, and given that there were no changes I don't see why you would want to anyway.

Comment: It clearly says "redeploy" not "restart." I, for instance, need to redeploy (not restart), because I am trying to Dockerize my app with Heroku, and as I'm debugging, I don't want to potentially pollute my git tree. It's how I ended up on this SO question.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, it did an actual build and release without any commit, contrary to one other post that only does a release:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
heroku builds:create --source-url https://user:token@api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repo name>/tarball/master/ --app <app-name>
```

Source: https://help.heroku.com/I3E6QPQN/how-do-i-force-a-new-deploy-without-adding-a-commit-to-my-github-repo

Answer (score 0):

you can easily redeploy your applicaiton via GUI by

- choosing the application you want to redeploy
- visiting the deploy page https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/ your-app-name /deploy/github

Now go to the bottom most(on deploy page) and find section `Manual Deploy` and click `deploy branch`

Answer (score -5):

For `stop` the `heroku` app uses :

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=0
```

And for `start` it uses :

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
```