# git not able to detect any change when a heroku buildpack is setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have built a rails app that I've deployed on Heroku. I was trying to use an API that relies on phantomjs, so I needed this package to be working on my Heroku server. I do this by:

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs
```

The buildpack gets added successfully to my app, and I get the following message:

```
Buildpack added. Next release on <myappname> will use:
  1. heroku/ruby
  2. https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs
Run git push heroku master to create a new release using these buildpacks.
```

However, when I run `git push heroku master`, it says that everything is up to date, so I am somehow not able to create a new release using this buildpack. Would appreciate help on where I've misunderstood this concept and get phantomjs running on my app server on Heroku. Things I have already tried:

1. Logging onto my Heroku server and searching for a phantomjs binary. I couldn't find one and I guess it's because the binary is dumped only when an instance of the app is accessed
2. Restarting my app's heroku server by `heroku restart`
3. Searching SO, and someone with a similar problem says they had to do a 'recommit' but I don't think that is the issue here since `git` is not able to detect any change in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't notice any changes because there aren't any changes to notice.

`heroku buildpacks:add` doesn't do anything to your local filesystem. It simply tells Heroku to add another buildpack when it builds your application. There's nothing new to push.

You can [redeploy your existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41345744/354577) or add some meaningfull changes, create a new commit, and push that.