# Deploy branch on Heroku via API

Tags: github, heroku

I have an application set up on heroku that is automatically deployed via GitHub. That setup is great and I don't want to change anything.

There is a use case now where I need to deploy the application from time to time without code changes (the build process fetches some recent data).

I can easily redeploy an app by going to the user interface and clicking "deploy a branch". However I would love to do this via an API. I could not find anything that helped achieve this in the [Heroku Platform API Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference).

I can create a Deployment via the [GitHub deployment API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/deployments/) but that doesn't seem to trigger a deployment on Heroku.

Any leads on how I can trigger a deployment for a specific app on Heroku?

Edit: I can't really make use of the answer [Redeploy Heroku app without code changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345744/redeploy-heroku-app-without-code-changes) as there is no answer that offers this functionality via an HTTP API.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However I need to be able to do this via an HTTP API.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku doesn't currently have a public API for GitHub Sync. So you will need to use their Platform API to [create a build](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#build-create).

GitHub gives you a tar.gz under the URL `https://github.com/<organization>/<repository>/archive/master.zip` (you need to pass an authorization token in the headers of course).

Using curl, you can do the following:

```
curl -n -v https://github.com/<organization>/<repository>/archive/master.zip
```

That URL will be a redirection to a URL on GitHub authenticated to allow the download. Reuse that URL to create an Heroku build:

```
curl -n -X POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/<app name>/builds \
  -d '{
  "source_blob": {
    "url": "<the URL fetched before>",
    "version": "<the version of the code you're trying to deploy>"
  }
}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

That will trigger a new build, downloading the code from GitHub. Effectively doing the same as GitHub Sync internally does.

You can also see this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-and-release-using-the-api

Comment: The solution worked for me. However the generated github URL expires after a while so I wonder if there is a way to pass in the authentication via URL.

Comment: There is no way to get a permanent generated URL (that's basically an S3 URL with a timed credential). You need to follow the redirection first every time.

Comment: Turns out there is a way to do this without fetching the redirect. With this URL pattern you can use your github token every time: https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/tarball/:branch?access_token=:token

Comment: @leifg nope, with the new github api, you must pass the access token as a header. And after you do that, it will return the `redirect` link which is temporary