# System limit for number of file watchers reached - create-react-app production deploy on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I am using create-react-app which is continuously deployed to Heroku.The last 2 deploys failed on Heroku and it threw this error

```
2022-02-27T23:29:12.758222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=647M(125.4%)
2022-02-27T23:29:12.781765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2022-02-27T23:29:33.512810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=674M(130.3%)
2022-02-27T23:29:33.535558+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

2022-02-27T21:22:01.870428+00:00 app[web.1]: Error from chokidar (/app/src): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/app/src/routes.ts'

2022-02-27T21:22:01.870532+00:00 app[web.1]: Error from chokidar (/app/src): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/app/src/setupTests.ts'

...
```

And there are.

I haven't changed any config since it was working correctly. A few hours of research couldn't help me as there were only post about the same problem but related to `npm start`, which is solved by increasing `max_user_watches`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is purely a React application it should use virtually *no* memory.

Build a production release and serve it as static files. Nothing needs to happen server-side other than serving up those files. The easiest way to do that for a `create-react-app` application on Heroku us to use [the `mars/create-react-app-buildpack`](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack):

> **This buildpack deploys a React UI as a static web site.** The Nginx web server provides optimum performance and security for the runtime.

[Configure your application to use this buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-buildpacks-set-buildpack):

```
heroku buildpacks:set mars/create-react-app
```

Then [redeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41345744/354577).