# whenever i try to push in Heroku,i get this error ."Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH." how to resolve?

Tags: heroku

Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
remote:          error: subprocess-exited-with-error
remote:
remote:          × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
remote:          │ exit code: 1
remote:          ╰─> [6 lines of output]
remote:              Checking for Rust toolchain...
remote:
remote:              Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
remote:              This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
remote:              the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/
remote:
remote:              [end of output]
remote:
remote:          note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
remote:        error: metadata-generation-failed
remote:
remote:        × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
remote:        ╰─> See above for output.
remote:
remote:        note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
remote:        hint: See above for details.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed

Comment: Seems pretty obvious: heroku is complaining that it's noticed that the project require rust, but you didn't mention rust in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app), one for Rust and another for Python.

Rust is not officially supported, but [several community options exist](https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=rust). Pick one, then configure your application:

1. Set your application to use the Python buildpack:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
   ```
2. Add your chosen Rust buildpack:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 YOUR_CHOSEN_BUILDPACK
   ```
3. Run `heroku buildpacks` to ensure they are correct. You should see the Rust buildpack first, and the Python buildpack second.
4. Finally, [redeploy your application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41345744/354577).