# webpack: not found -When deploying my app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, npm-install

I am trying to deploy my node.js app to heroku using github but build is keep getting rejected giving error "webpack: not found".Not sure whatelse I am missing in my scripts.
1)I have tried adding node version to my package.json.
2)I do have webpack installed and included in my dev dependencies.
3)I do added "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --dev"to my scripts section to the root of package.json but still no luck.
Please see the build log below :-

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.17.0...
       Using default npm version: 8.15.0
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       > JATE@1.0.0 install
       > cd client && npm install
       
       
       added 2 packages, and audited 3 packages in 14s
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       added 162 packages, and audited 163 packages in 22s
       
       15 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > JATE@1.0.0 build
       > cd client && npm run build
       
       
       > build
       > webpack --mode production
       
/tmp/build-3dc3f907.sh: 1: webpack: not found
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Please see the package.json for my client folder

```
{
  "name": "JATE",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "author": "2U",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.3.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "code-mirror-themes": "^1.0.0",
    "idb": "^6.1.2"
  }
}
```

Please see the package.json for my root folder

```
{
  "name": "JATE",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run server\" \"cd client && npm run dev\"",
    "start": "npm run build && cd server && node server.js",
    "server": "cd server nodemon server.js --ignore client",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "client": "cd client && npm start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install your client dependencies via this script in your main `package.json`:

```json
"install": "cd client && npm install",
```

But, by default, Heroku doesn't run `npm install`:

> Heroku uses the lockfiles, either the `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`, to install the expected dependency tree, so be sure to check those files into git to ensure the same dependency versions across environments. If you are using npm, Heroku will use `npm ci` to set up the build environment.

As a result, your `install` script isn't being called.

You can configure Heroku to run `npm install` instead (see below), but before you do that I suggest you consider the impact. [`npm ci` exists for this kind of use case](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-ci#description):

> This command is similar to [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install), except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment -- or any situation where you want to make sure you're doing a clean install of your dependencies. It can be significantly faster than a regular npm install by skipping certain user-oriented features. It is also more strict than a regular install, which can help catch errors or inconsistencies caused by the incrementally-installed local environments of most npm users.
>
> In short, the main differences between using `npm install` and `npm ci` are:
>
> - The project **must** have an existing `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json`.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in `package.json`, `npm ci` will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - `npm ci` can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a `node_modules` is already present, it will be automatically removed before `npm ci` begins its install.
> - It will never write to `package.json` or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

To continue using `npm ci`, one option is to have your main `build` script call `npm ci` in your client folder:

```json
"build": "cd client && npm ci && npm run build",
```

If you still want to use `npm install` after reading all of this, [set the `USE_NPM_INSTALL` environment variable to `true`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#using-npm-install):

```
heroku config:set USE_NPM_INSTALL=true
```

Then [redeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41345744/354577).