# how can I install with tag "legacy-peer-deps" on heroku

Tags: heroku, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my app onto heroku, yet I receive a build erorr where it fails to install the dependencies using npm install. Is there anyway I can install with "legacy-peer-deps"?

Thank you so much...

I tried editing my procifile file with the following contents in it

```
web: npm install --legacy-peer-deps
web: npm start
```

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, you should resolve the underlying dependency issue so your application works without this option. But you should be able to [configure it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#configuring-npm) by setting [environment variable](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#environment-variables) ("config var" in Heroku-speak).

I believe [the `legacy-peer-deps` setting](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#legacy-peer-deps) will do the trick:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS=true
```

Then you'll need to [redeploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41347235/354577).

Alternatively, you could add [an `.npmrc` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#npmrc-files) to your project:

```ini
legacy-peer-deps = true
```

Commit it, then redeploy.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to fix your dependency issues, but in case there's still the need to deploy it as is, the **easiest way** to do so would be the following:

1. Go to your app account on Heroku.
2. Go to settings.
3. Click on 'Reveal Config Vars'.
4. Add as key:

> NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS

5. Add as value:

> true

6. Deploy

Good luck!